# How to add an NSEvent to a Property List?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, property-list

I'd like to encode an `NSEvent` using `NSPropertyListSerialization`, but NSPropertyListSerialization only accepts NSData, NSString, NSArray, NSDictionary, NSDate, and NSNumber objects.

Is there a recommended way to convert an NSEvent to a NSPropertyListSerialization-capable NSDictionary (and to restore an NSEvent from such an NSDictionary)?

Comment: Why on earth are you trying to serialize an `NSEvent`?

Comment: I'd like to record interactions with an application, and be able to later replay those interactions to drive the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this situation you need to handle saving and restoring the object yourself. Or rather, the pieces of the object you're interested in, either by putting each value in an NSDictionary or storing them separately and using the values to create a new object when your class is decoded.

This situation is a little weird since you usually don't create or store NSEvent objects. If you're doing something like storing the last touch coordinate, consider using an CGPoint instead. Not only will you reduce your memory footprint by a small amount, but you can then use an NSValue to serialize the point.

Comment: Thanks.  I would like to store a variety of NSEvent types, however, so the coordinates alone wouldn't represent all the necessary data to construct a new NSEvent.

Comment: yeah you will have to roll your own implementation, save what you are interested in.